# Making $6$ digits numbers by the digits $2,3,3,5,5,5,5$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many $6$ digits number we can generate by the digits $2,3,3,5,5,5,5$ ?

To solve this problem I considered three cases because we have $7$ digits and looking for six digit number.

1. Numbers without $2\Rightarrow\quad\dfrac{6!}{4!2!}=15$
2. Numbers without one $3\Rightarrow\quad\dfrac{6!}{4!}=30$
3. Numbers without one $5\Rightarrow\quad\dfrac{6!}{3!2!}=60$

So the answer is $15+30+60=105$.

---

But The book I'm reading from used another method:

Number of $6$ digits permutation from these $7$digits=Number of $7$ digits permutation from these $7$digits= $\dfrac{7!}{2!4!}=105$.

But I don't completely why permutation of  $6$ digits is equal to permutation of all the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline\hline
2s&3s&5s&6-\text{digit numbers}\\
\hline
1&1&4&\frac{6!}{4!}=30\\
\hline
1&2&3&\frac{6!}{2!3!}=60\\
\hline
0&2&4&\frac{6!}{2!4!}=15
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\hline
\text{Total 6-digit numbers}&30+60+15=105
\end{array}

Your calculations are correct, as shown in the table. Regarding your question as to why the seven-digit permutations work, observe that every six-digit permutation can be changed into a seven-digit permutation by appending the unused digit. There is a one-to-one correspondence between the two.

$$233555\color{magenta}{5}$$
$$253553\color{magenta}{5}$$
$$255553\color{magenta}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already knew it and I stated my issue in the second part of the question.

Comment: Kindly read the full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have arranged the first six digits, there is only one choice for the seventh digit.  Thus, the number of arranging all seven digits also gives the total number of ways of arranging the first six of those seven digits.